# view is not visible in adapter's item file

Tags: java, android

I have added a view between imageView and textView in adapter's item file, it is visible in layout file but it is not showing up in runtime.

I have increased its width size and margins but no results. I also used layout inspector in 3D mode but the view line was no visible in that too.[this is my XML item file and the view with id viewOne is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqih5.png)

Comment: Provide adapter code and layout..

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView ? Item changed ? item UI changed ?use adapter notifyItemChanged
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ1pN.jpg)

Adapter notify Api Pic

Comment: I don't want to refresh the adapter class I'm just showing the data from the API, and in that, I am showing 1 image and its description and to separate these two I have added a view

Comment: ImageView ? this height no value ,you can write height a value